# MySQL Default DATETIME value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'd like to accomplish something like the following in a MySQL Create table action

```
date_created datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATETIME,  
date_updated datetime NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_DATETIME,
```

Once again, this is a MySQL create table action and these are two of the fields in my table.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this

[TIMESTAMP Properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

From the link you can use

```
CREATE TABLE t (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                             ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE t (ts TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                             DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Is there not one for datetime?

Comment: There is also an explicitly documented restriction that you can only have the default and auto-update on a single column - not split across two columns as requested.  And only one column can be treated thusly.  Seems like an odd restriction; the scenario in the question is very common.  If you could do it on two columns, then the 'date_created' column would be given a default without the ON UPDATE clause and the date updated would have both the default and ON UPDATE clauses.

Comment: This restriction [has been lifted](http://optimize-this.blogspot.com/2012/04/datetime-default-now-finally-available.html) as of MySQL 5.6.5.